# Maxwell's equation. E and H. Two homogeneous but different media

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I need your help in explanation/understanding the following question:

The electric and magnetic fields have at an interface between two homogeneous media the continuity conditions.
How can it be explained by help Maxwell's equations?

Answer (score 1):

Is your question "Why are the Fresnel formulas derived using continuity relations and not the Maxwell equations ?" ?

Note that the continuity relations follow from the Maxwell equations.

Later added:

You can find the detailed discussion that you may be looking for here:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-013-electromagnetics-and-applications-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec2.pdf

Comment: actually no.
If one considers a planar interface between two homogeneous but different media. I would like to explain the continuity conditions for electrical and magnetic fields at such an interface with specific applications with deriving the law of reflection and/or Snell’s law of refraction from these conditions and with using Maxwell equations.

Answer (score 0):

The continuity conditions *are* the Maxwell equations, in boundary form. As such, they are obtained from the integral form of the Maxwell equations in exactly same way that the differential form is derived:

- You start off with your geometric configuration (i.e. in bulk or a surface, for the differential and boundary forms respectively).
- You choose an appropriate gaussian surface and/or amperian loop for your integrals.
- You make your surface/loop small enough that the fields can be expanded locally as low-order Taylor series.
- You simplify as appropriate.

The only difference between the two procedures is the choice of surface/loop and the limiting procedure, i.e. for the boundary form you will need to be careful about the order in which you take limits on the different dimensions of your integration manifold.

If you want more details, the [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-013-electromagnetics-and-applications-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec2.pdf) provided by @my2cts is perfectly appropriate; if you want a full derivation to be posted here then that is a good deal broader than what's supported by our format; the same goes for a derivation of the Fresnel equations and the Snell refraction law as an application of the boundary forms of the Maxwell equations, which is presented in any reasonable physical-optics textbook.